# Unselect a Select Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a "select" input that is programmed to open up a modal box when clicked to get some information before proceeding.  That part all works great.

The problem is that once the modal box is up, the select dropdown options are all still visible.  I want that select input to go back to being a normal, not clicked on at all, select box.

What javascript or jquery code can I use to make that select dropdown clear away?

Comment: document.body.focus() should work

Comment: Good idea... didn't work though. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is more correct to move handler from `click` to `change`. In this case select will be close and keyboard changes also will be processed

Comment: Even though this solution doesn't work for me (I need the alert to come up before they even get to look around and change the select) it's a great idea and merits being chosen the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this instead:

```
$('#mySelect').focus(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // code here
});
```

If that does't work, try using the preventDefault() with the click event.
The focus will at least allows users navigating fields with the keyboard (tab, etc) instead of the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

**Prior to jQuery 1.6**

```
$('#mySelectBox :selected').attr('selected', '');
```

**jQuery 1.6 and higher**

```
$('#mySelectBox :selected').removeProp('selected', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can do it with standard select tag. Maybe because it still has focus. What I did when I needed a customized select tag is to avoid the select tag completely and use a button which graphically looks like the select button. Look at [this page](http://birds.cz/avif/obs.php?request_id=258791070#sf=1&dm=0&url_fmt_ver=0.2&iDisplayLength=25&pager_PaginationType=full_numbers&iDisplayStart=0&iSortCol_0=0&iSortDir_0=desc&current_sf_changed=0&d%5bSpecies%5d=&d%5bActivity%5d=&d%5bCount%5d=&d%5bObserver%5d=&d%5bmunicipality%5d=&d%5bSiteName%5d=&d%5bDateType%5d=2&d%5bDateExact%5d=&d%5bDateFrom%5d=&d%5bDateTo%5d=&d%5bSeasonFrom%5d=&d%5bSeasonTo%5d=&d%5bYearFrom%5d=&d%5bYearTo%5d=) - look at the TAX button and the button to the left of it. There is no select tag, but it works great.